# How to keep clicking element when visible - SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium

I need to keep clicking on element unless it turns invisible.

my code:

```
 try:
    element = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content']//form//div[2]//span[@id='main_content']")))
    if element:
        while element:
            submit.click()
except:
    pass
```

current code clicks once or none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original loop might only click once because `element` is of type `WebElement`, not `Boolean`, so `element == True` will always return false.

I would change up your code structure a bit, to avoid storing the `WebElement` in `element` variable & locate fresh instance each time loop iterates:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# find your submit button outside loop
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("some_locator")

# perform this loop indefinitely until break condition is met
while True:
    try:

        # optional: You may need to locate submit button with each loop iteration
        # submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("some_locator")

        # attempt to click submit button
        submit.click()

        # check if element is visible -- this will throw TimeoutException if not
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content']//form//div[2]//span[@id='main_content']")))

    except TimeoutException:
        # case: element is no longer visible, so break out of loop
        break
```

This code runs a `while True:` loop where it first attempts to click element, then catches any exception & breaks out of loop if exception is thrown. In this case, exception is thrown when button located is no longer visible, which will throw `TimeoutException`. So once element is no longer visible & `TimeoutException` gets thrown, code breaks out of loop.

I changed `except:` to `except TimeoutException:` because this is the exception `WebDriverWait` throws when element is invisible. If we just leave `except:` with no specific exception to catch, then you may end up with a buried `StaleElementReferenceException` that happens on `submit.click()`.

I also added some commented-out code to fix the `StaleElementReferenceException` in the case that `submit.click()` DOES throw this exception.

Comment: I need to keep clicking the button until the element is visible. I forgot to share with my button selector (submit.click()). In this case should I put while true under "if element == True" ?

Comment: I just saw that you are clicking `submit` button -- I updated my solution to take that into account. We do not need to store `element` anywhere, because `WebDriverWait` will throw `TimeoutException` if element is invisible. Do not use `if element == True`, because `WebElement` type will never equal `True`.

Comment: Still clicks only once :(

Comment: My theory is that your XPath for the desired element is affecting this outcome - it’s possible page structure changes after first click. If `click()` is only executed once, then that means the `TimeoutException` was hit. This means the element located by your XPath was not visible. It’s hard to troubleshoot this any further without the additional HTML from your page or a link to the page being automated.

Comment: I figured it out :) I was receiving stale element exception so I just redeclared the submit under while True and it worked, thanks :)

Comment: Glad that comment ended up helping you out.